# How to use re.sub to replace a match by repl which contains '\g' in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

As in the doc, if `\g` in repl, python will looking for the next char `<`.
Unfortunately I need repl contain `\g`, and I cannot put raw string `r'repl_string'` in the position of repl since it is a string variable. And if I put re.escape('repl_string') it works but the result is not I want, since it escapes most of the chars.

What should I do?

Here is the code I actually have:

```
newline = '<p align="center"><img src="https://s0.wp.com/latex.php?latex=%5Cdisplaystyle+%7B%5Cbf+P%7D%28+%7C%5Cfrac%7BS_n+-+n+%5Cmu%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D+%5Csigma%7D%7C+%5Cgeq+%5Clambda+%29+%5C+%5C+%5C+%5C+%5C+%282%29&amp;bg=ffffff&amp;fg=000000&amp;s=0" alt="\\displaystyle {\x08f P}( |\x0crac{S_n - n \\mu}{\\sqrt{n} \\sigma}| \\geq \\lambda ) \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ (2)" title="\\displaystyle {\x08f P}( |\x0crac{S_n - n \\mu}{\\sqrt{n} \\sigma}| \\geq \\lambda ) \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ (2)" class="latex" width="173" height="38" srcset="https://s0.wp.com/latex.php?latex=%5Cdisplaystyle+%7B%5Cbf+P%7D%28+%7C%5Cfrac%7BS_n+-+n+%5Cmu%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D+%5Csigma%7D%7C+%5Cgeq+%5Clambda+%29+%5C+%5C+%5C+%5C+%5C+%282%29&amp;bg=ffffff&amp;fg=000000&amp;s=0&amp;zoom=2 2x" scale="2">'

re.sub(r'<img.*?>', '\\[ {\\bf P}( |\\frac{S_n - n \\mu}{\\sqrt{n} \\sigma}| \\geq \\lambda ) \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ (2)\\]', newline, count = 1)
```

Comment: Double escape the ``\`` in  `\g` (i.e. `"\\\\g"`,or `r"\\g"`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As I said I cannot do the `r"\\g"` since repl is a string variable, and `re.escape(repl)` will escape too much I think. I still don't fully get the behavior of my code when using re.escape. I'll take a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: You may use `my_repl.replace(r'\g', r'\\g')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I thing this might work. I'll try it tomorrow morning. :-)

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `\g` is turned into `\\g` in the replacement string. More, you actually need to replace all backslashes in the replacement pattern with two backslashes to prevent further issues.

Use

```
rpl = rpl.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

See  a [demo](https://ideone.com/41r4RC):

```
import re
rpl = r'\geq \1'
# print(re.sub(r'\d+', rpl, 'Text 1')) # sre_constants.error: missing group name
# print(re.sub(r'\d+', r'some \1', 'Text 1')) # sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
print(re.sub(r'\d+', rpl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), 'Text 1')) # => Text \geq \1 (as expected)
```